# Selenium Fixed Thread Pool performance issues

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium

I am currently trying to fire off a large number of selenium processes via

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

and am noticing performance issues.

The code that I'm deploying I first test and keep a copy of in a TestModule that runs the process once and uses the apache Stopwatch to monitor the time it takes to run the single thread.

When I run this code I see the following results:

```
Stopwatch time: 00:00:11.043
```

This is the time it takes from the initial driver.get(MY_WEBSITE_URL) all the way through inspecting elements and other tasking I wish to accomplish.

However, if I do the following in code, I get really slow results.

```
QueryAgent queryAgent = new QueryAgent();
queryAgent.startUp();
new Thread(queryAgent).start();
```

Inside of QueryAgent

```
 private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);


MyPojo pojo = MyPojoImpl.doStuff();
```

All of the code inside of "doStuff()" is the same code in my Test Module.  If I am running 10 threads and each one should take no more than ~20 seconds to process.  I would expect to see ~30 runs accomplished in a minute ~1800 in an hour.

Yet, looking at my logs I'm getting no more than 5 requests in a minute.

### Is there a better way to run these requests in parallel?

EDIT1:

After looking at the comment below and doing a "top" it appears that once I hit about 4 instances of phantomjs - my CPUs are hitting 100%

But my memory usage is shy of 1GB.  At this point it appears the bottle neck is the CPU(s).  Any ideas?

Comment: Keeping in mind [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), what are the specs of the machine?

Comment: AWS t2 Micro  2 CPU 4 GB Ram  2 GB Swap Space

Comment: how are you finding the web elements? Xpath is recommended typically?